# Firebase Authentication - users not receiving verification emails

Tags: firebase, email, firebase-authentication, email-verification

I have built an app that uses email & password authentication from Firebase, to enable users to log in, as per the Firebase documentation. The app itself uses Flutter as the coding language. I also have email verification enabled, to prevent spam accounts.

When a user adds their email address and password and clicks 'submit', they're given a notification telling them to check their emails for the verification link, which they must do before being allowed to log in.

The problem I am having is that users do not receive the verification email, so cannot log in. I've come across similar questions on this forum, where the answers have centred around checking spam/junk folders. I have asked the users to do this but they still have not received the email.

I've also tried using my own SMTP server, which is one from which I know I can send emails. Even with this, the users do not receive their verification email. This makes me think the emails aren't being generated/sent, as opposed to them being sent and not being received.

Can anyone suggest why this might be the case? Why is it that users are not receiving the verification email and what can I do to correct this?

Comment: Can you share your code? Without more precise details we cannot help you...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The app itself only has email sign-in capabilities, as opposed to registration as well. I know that all users who already have an account are able to log in, no problem. Users are able to create the account on my WordPress website, using a Firebase integration plugin (TechCater). Their accounts are created in Firebase, but it somehow isn't sending the verification emails.

Comment: "but it somehow isn't sending the verification emails." what exact mechanism send the verification emails?

Comment: As mentioned it's import to include your code as SO is a coding specific forum. If it's not a coding issue, including it can help us eliminate that variable. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @James I have the same problem, were you able to solve it?

Comment: @MarcosEchagüe Unfortunately not. I tried recreating my Firebase project and custom domains etc, basically everything I could think of. In the end, I just ended up removing the email verification settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use custom domain, sometimes emails go in spam folder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).